# Fingerprint conflict on virtual cluster server

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtualhost, virtualbox-networking

I created three virtual machines (Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS), one for control and two nodes. Control is working fine, I can access it, however when I try to access node1 I get this error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the (omissis) key sent by the remote host is
(omissis)
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/(omissis)/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/(omissis)/.ssh/known_hosts:11
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/(omissis)/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[(vm IP, omissis)]:3022"
Host key for [(vm IP, omissis)]:3022 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I believe that this comes from the fact that the virtual machines share the IP address, however the `known_hosts` file in `~/.ssh` has already saved the control one in it.
I would like to access both of them (as many as I want really) simultaneously. How do I do that? How do I force another known host to be added to the list?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ubuntu 22 LTS?  So you're asking about a Ubuntu Core 22 server system?  (LTS isn't used for the *year* products of Ubuntu as all come with 10 years of support; only the *year.month* products have LTS & non-LTS releases)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, however the output of ```cat /etc/*-release``` is
```DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian```

Comment: You're not using Ubuntu Core 22 server system, but Ubuntu 22.04 which is a different product.  Ubuntu 22.04 was released in 2022-April (thus 22.04), where the 22 systems released only last month in July 2022 (they are alternate server products based on 22.04).  22 != 22.04 so please be precise with details; there are differences between 22 & 22.04 on which it's based.  Please correct your question

Comment: FYI:   22 refers to the *snap* only products, they are smaller than the 22.04 system on which they're based; which makes them faster to spin up, use less resources etc (great for devices, cloud etc)... and being *snap* only, when you upgrade to a later release - no user apps require upgrade (ie. avoiding a hassle of *deb* based 22.04).... They do however have differences, apps run confined, less powerful etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521473).

There are two possible solutions.

1. Copying server fingerprints (discouraged due to security issues)

If you match the files that contain the fingerprints(`/etc/ssh/ssh_host*`), no errors will be given for mismatching fingerprints.

2. Creating multiple `known_hosts` files on the client side

By adding host configs to `~/.ssh/config`, it is possible to use different fingerprints that point to the same machine. For more info, see [`man ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

Example (from the link):

```
Host windows.dualbootbox
    Hostname 192.168.10.20
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/windows.dualbootbox.known_hosts

Host ubuntu.dualbootbox
    Hostname 192.168.10.20
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/ubuntu.dualbootbox.known_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem in a GUI fashion.
First, on VirtualBox go to `file` and `Host Network Manager`

[image: host network manager]

Next, `create`

[image: p2]

Go to you soon to be virtual node's `settings` and then `network`

[image: nat1]

Select `NAT` and then `Port Forwarding Rules`. Create a new Port Forwarding Rule with the little `+` button on the right top corner.

[image]

In order

```
Name: ssh
Protocol: TCP
Host Port: 3022
Guest Port: 22
```

Press `ok` and go to `Adapter 2`. Enable it and select `Host-only Adapter`

[image]

Enable `Adapter 3` and chose `Bridged Adapter`

[image]

You are now set to go, repeat each step (except for the first) for each node of your cluster. If you do this you won't have IP conflicts of sort.

Comment: I have kind of similar setup (2 host machines, multiple virtual machines. And the host machines are only reachable through a VPN on a third machine). My initial setup was having all the ssh ports different and routed to the virtual machine via iptables, but it was a headache to set up for the first time. My recommendation for your setup would be going with option 2 provided on my answer, but if this suits better for you, go with it.